# Facebook Comments Widget and Open Graph Object

Tags: facebook, comments, facebook-opengraph

Please help! I can't find how to do this anywhere... Is this possible?

1. I have a facebook app created with an OG Object (called, say, `MyObject`), also, in my app I want to use the comments widget.
2. I have dynamic URLs created for my `MyObject"` objects like

> http://example.com/myobject.php?=4

and those pages have the right OG tags to identify the OG object...

3. I add the comments widget to those pages with `data-href="http://example.com/myobject.php?=4"`
4. I want facebook to post the comments to the timeline like:

> "User commented on a MyObject"

and the corresponding data below, instead of

> "User commented on a Link"

as it keeps doing.

Please help!

Thanks

Comment: is there a workaround for this ?

Answer (score 0):

> I want facebook to post the comments to the timeline like: "User commented on a MyObject" and the corresponding data below, instead of "User commented on a Link" as it keeps doing...

The Comments plugin has no clue that you have defined any objects in your app – to it `http://mysite.com/myobject.php?=4` is just an ordinary URL, and therefor it posts to the timeline as "User commented on a Link".

If you want to have it the other way, you will have to set up a “comment” *action* in your app as well (probably not namend “comment”, because Facebook might not approve an action with that phrasing) – and have to publish that action yourself, with a message from the user (which would be his comment on the object in this case).

But you’ll have to implement the commenting process yourself than as well, I think – the Comments plugin itself does not offer that functionality.